# Identify / separate sorts of failure

Tags: r, survival, reliability, weibull-distribution

I ran a Weibull analysis on data of devices which consists mainly of failures over time (80 % died, 20 % are still alive). In total there are around ~4500 devices.
After conducting this analysis I received this plot by means of [WeibullR](http://www.openreliability.org/weibull-r-weibull-analysis-on-r/):

[image: img]

After some digging on the internet I read here and there that this shape of the curve means, that there are different failure reasons within the data.
So, my objective now is to separate these different failure mechanisms. Surely it's not given in the data. Is there a way backward, like using the plot resp. the distribution somehow to separate them reasonably?

Comment: This curve might also mean that a Weibull distribution isn't appropriate. Have you tried other parametric models?

Comment: not yet, I thought it quite reasonably that there are multiple failures involved resp. from domain knowledge I know that there have to be different failures.

Answer (score 1):

If your domain knowledge suggests that there are different failure modes possible but you can't identify the mode directly in a failed device, you might consider a parametric [mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) that allows for different baseline hazards. In principle that could help distinguish survival functions associated with different failure modes, although it couldn't tell you precisely which device failed via which mode.

I don't have experience with such models. A quick search shows the [`mixPHM` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mixPHM) for mixtures of parametric proportional-hazard models, which includes your Weibull model. That package requires you to specify how many components to include in your mixture. There are presumably ways to estimate the number of components from the data too, but that's far outside my expertise.

Comment: Thank you, I'll explore this package!

Comment: btw, components are what exactly in this context, here?

Comment: @Ben the "components" would be the Weibull distributions describing each of the individual failure modes. If you think there are 2 distinct modes of failure each described by a (separate) Weibull distribution, then there are 2 components.